# Como digitar por voz Phonegap Framework?

Tags: apache-cordova, mobile, jquery-mobile

Estou fazendo uma aplicação, usando o framework phonegap junto com jQuery Mobile. A questão é: Gostaria de acrescentar a função de digitação por voz, sendo que meu campo `input` é do tipo number, ou seja aceita apenas números, mas o phonegap não tem tal plugin ou tem? Alguem saberia me dizer. Terei que fazer nativa a app?

Answer (score 1):

Existe um plugin do phonegap, se chama [speech-recognition](http://plugreg.com/plugin/an-rahulpandey/speech-recognition-plugin-ios).